# Flutter HTTP issues

Tags: flutter, flutter-http

With the new update, some HTTP functionality has changed. This function used to work and now it does not. Can someone explain what changed?

```
import 'package:http/http.dart';

    void getData() async {
    Response response = await get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
    Map data = JsonDecode(responce.body);
    print(data);
    }

lib/pages/loading.dart:24:37: Error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uri'.
 - 'Uri' is from 'dart:core'.
      Response response = await get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
```

Comment: There are some potential errors in that code, can you show the error message of your interest?

Comment: lib/pages/loading.dart:24:37: Error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uri'.
 - 'Uri' is from 'dart:core'.
      Response response = await get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
                                    ^

Comment: Try the code below....

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void getData() async {
  var response = await http.get(Uri.parse('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1'));
  var data = jsonDecode(response.body) as Map;
  print(data);
}
```

**UPDATE:**  Inserting code for *WorldTimeApi*

NetService:

```
class NetService {
  static Future<T?> getJson<T>(String url, {int okCode = 200}) {
    return http.get(Uri.parse(url))
      .then((response) {
        if (response.statusCode == okCode) {
          return jsonDecode(response.body) as T;
        }
        PrintService.showDataNotOK(response);
        return null;
      })
      .catchError((err) => PrintService.showError(err));
  }
}
```

Main:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:_samples2/networking.dart';

class WorldTimeApi {
  static const _url = 'http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone';

  static FutureOr<void> fetchTime(String relPath) async {
    await NetService.getJson(_url + relPath)
      .then((response) => print(response))
      .whenComplete(() => print('\nFetching done!'));
  }
}

void main(List<String> args) async {
  await WorldTimeApi.fetchTime('/America/Los_Angeles');
  print('Done!');
}
```

Result:

```
{abbreviation: PST, client_ip: 179.6.56.125, datetime: 2021-03-09T17:24:09.367903-08:00, day_of_week: 2, day_of_year: 68, dst: false, dst_from: null, dst_offset: 0, dst_until: null, raw_offset: -28800, timezone: America/Los_Angeles, unixtime: 1615339449, utc_datetime: 2021-03-10T01:24:09.367903+00:00, utc_offset: -08:00, week_number: 10}

Fetching done!
Done!
```

Comment: Thank you. I was able to get it running by parsing the Uri. Just unsure why the first code sample used to work but now does not. 

Maybe you can help me with a second issue. 

if I use a https link for example 
var response = await http.get(Uri.parse('http://worldtimeapi.org/timezone/America/Los_Angeles')); 
I get this error message: flutter: Bad state: Insecure HTTP is not allowed by platform:

What is the ideal way to handle nonsecure links?

Comment: I don't know how you will be coding, but `http` works fine for me. I've inserted my code above.

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

// Await the http get response, then decode the json-formatted response.
Response response = await get(Uri.parse('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1'));

Map data = jsonDecode(response.body);

print(jsonResponse);
```